# Angular 4 delete request to backend

Tags: node.js, angular

My problem is that the delete function isn't working.

On backend i'v got a simple PSQL Query which is working as well. If I tested via postman it delete the table row what I want. The problem is that the button doesn't working. I think there will be with select things...

If you have any kind of better idea that this method, please comment. What I need is only that the button call the backend function what will delete the selected row from PSQL Table.

**Frontend:**

**Service:**

```
deleteImportantNote(id){
        return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/deleteimportantnote'+id )
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Component:

```
deleteImportantNote(comment){
  var comments = this.comment_text;

  this.dashboardimportantnoteService.deleteImportantNote(comment.id)
    .subscribe(comment => {
      if(comment.n == 1){
        for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){
          if(comments[i].id == comment.id){
            comments.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    })
}
```

Comment table:

export class Comment{

```
 comment_text: string;
 country: string;
 username: string;
 id:number;
 public selected: string;
```

}

HTML:

```
    <div *ngFor="let comment of comment.comment ">
        <div *ngIf="comment.country === 'USA'">
          <mat-list>
               <b>ID:</b>{{comment.id}} <b>USER:</b>{{comment.username}} <b>COMMENT:</b> {{comment.comment_text}} <b>COUNTRY:</b>{{comment.country}} <button mat-raised-button (click)="deleteImportantNote(); ngOnInit()">Delete</button>
            </mat-list>     
        </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
```

Comment: I think you're missing a slash in the route. `this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/deleteimportantnote/' + id)`

Comment: Thanks mate, you are awesome :)